# How to make sentences if I happened to be in these situations and and how I have to express myself in this situations

Tags: expressions

How to make sentences if I happened to be in these situations and how do I have to express myself in these situations?

> 1. Thorn into the sole of my leg.
> 2. Bitten by a snake.
> 3. Bitten by an ant.
> 4. If I walk in swampy land. ( if I'm feeling very difficult to walk and my feet repeatedly go inside of swamp)

Please help me to express myself in English when in these situations.

Comment: Is it snake or snack? Is it bitten or biten? After you post a question, try to review it and see if there are typos. You need to capitalize the personal pronoun "i".

Comment: All Edited just now

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: No, not a homework problem, I'm learning enlish expression.

Answer (score 4):

1. "Ouch! I stepped on a thorn." Or, "A thorn caught me in the side of my leg."
2. "Oh my God! A snake just bit me!" Or, "Help me! I've been bitten by a snake."
3. "I was bitten by an ant." Or, "Damn it! I just got an ant bite."
4. "My feet are sinking into the mud!" Or, "The swamp is sucking my feet deeper into the muck with each step I take!"